# model variables name are different from the csv file header

Tags: java, csv

I am trying to generate csv file using ICsvBeanWriter. The problem that I am facing is my model variables name are different from the csv file headers. Here, is my implementation

```
public class EmployeeTableRow { 
      String employeeName; 
      String employeeId; 
      String joiningDate; 
      String exitDate; 
} 
public class Test{ 
      public void getEmployeeCSV(){ 

                ICsvBeanWriter csvWriter = new CsvBeanWriter(response.getWriter(), CsvPreference.STANDARD_PREFERENCE);

                String[] header = {"employee_name", "employee_id", "joining_date", "exit_date"}; 
                csvWriter.writeHeader(header); 
                ArrayList<EmployeeTableRow>rows = getEmployeeTableRows(); 


                for (EmployeeTableRow row : rows) { 
                    csvWriter.write(row, header); 
                  } 

                csvWriter.close();

        } 

}
```

I am trying to find, if there is any way I could map the table column names to my model names.

Any help will be really appreciated.